# How to apply conditional format to scatter chart in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi

As captioned, there are no such function in filled color for format pane:
[scatter chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8RD1.png)

How to apply conditional format to scatter chart in powerbi? like from blue to red base on the amount.

No such function in this color pane.

Comment: any answer pls?